# Bored with the Internet

Tags: riddle

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #35: Restricted Title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/48337).</sup>

---

You, yeah you! Are you bored with the internet? Well here are some science/math themed jokes for you!

> 1. What is the angriest(not negative) process/operation in math?
> 2. What bad grade did larry receive in is programming class?
> 3. What do aliens call a mysterious and grim occurrence in space?
> 4. What do you call a zany, quantum particle?

Comment: Aren't we supposed to be burninating the [tag:humor] tag ... ?

Comment: fixed, and how do you add the link onto the word humor?

Comment: `[tag:tagname]` will give you the link. (Also works in posts and chat.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. > $\times$, because it's **cross**.
2. > **C++**?
3. Thanks to @noedne:

   > Dark matter?
4. > A **strange** quark.

Comment: All of those are right so far.

Comment: @noedne Thanks for the tip! :-) But please don't leave rot13'ed comments without mentioning that they're rot13 - it's really confusing to newcomers. Better not to obfuscate them at all than to post apparent gibberish without context.

Comment: @Randal'Thor You're right, and I usually do with a link, but I guess I forgot to.

Answer (score 4):

Borrowing off @Rand_al'Thor's answer

> 1. Multiplication (Cross)
>  2. C (Lower than C++, i suppose)
>  3. Dark Matter(s)? Perhaps Negative Energy?
>  4. Strange Quark

Comment: That is correct @AshwinKumar