# Back to the Future

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I slip through your fingers as sand in a sieve.
A brief moment, an eternity, is when I live.

I'm nothing at all, yet I contain everything.
Time travellers leave me, but I'm always waiting.

I'm always moving, yet you're always within me.
Held between mighty ones who can never win me.

---

<sub>Inspired by [Joe-You-Know's nice riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/66827/5373), and by [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/102/) via the [current Fortnightly Topic Challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6352/5373).</sub>

Comment: I really like the wording of this riddle.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you are

> The present

I slip through your fingers as sand in a sieve.

> The present moment is always fleeting, as sand in a sieve.

A brief moment,

> The present lasts no more than a moment.

an eternity, is when I live.

> But it is always the present.

I'm nothing at all,

> The present doesn't really have a duration, it's length is essentially zero.

yet I contain everything.

> Everything is contained in the present.

Time travellers leave me,

> Time travellers leave the present to move into the future, or past.

but I'm always waiting.

> I guess when a time traveller moves, they will move to a new present time, from their perspective.

I'm always moving,

> The present is ever-changing

yet you're always within me.

> You are always within the present moment.

Held between mighty ones who can never win me.

> The past and the future.

Comment: I was going to write this, beaten by a few seconds :\ +1

Comment: Well, I was going for easy, but maybe it ended up a bit *too* easy ...

Comment: @Randal'Thor Well, a riddle like this is good from time to time.

Comment: Were I to look at this puzzle from the point of view of the special theory of relativity, I might have some qualms about **both** the lines in the second stanza :-)

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT: Sniped by hexomino!**

Are you:

> The Present?

I slip through your fingers as sand in a sieve.

> The moment of the present is always moving, and we are always moving through time

A brief moment, an eternity, is when I live.

> It's but an instant, but we always exist in it

I'm nothing at all, yet I contain everything.

> It can be defined as infinitely small amount of time, but everything is always experiencing 'now'

Time travellers leave me, but I'm always waiting.

> Time travelers leave the present, but wherever/whenever they arrive will become their 'present'

I'm always moving, yet you're always within me.

> The present changes, but our existence moves along with it

Held between mighty ones who can never win me.

> Referring to the past and the future, much longer periods of time that we never get to exist in

Answer (score 5):

You are

> Love

I slip through your fingers as sand in a sieve.

> Love is hard to hold on to, especially if you're pining for someone you can't have

A brief moment, an eternity, is when I live.

> Love can last the briefest moments or forever.

I'm nothing at all, yet I contain everything.

> Love is everything, yet it's not physical or tangible

Time travellers leave me, but I'm always waiting.

> I believe this is a Doctor Who reference where the Doctor leaves Rose trapped in another dimension

I'm always moving, yet you're always within me.

> Love is fluid, but is always with you.

Held between mighty ones who can never win me.

> Reference to Helen of Troy, who was fought over but never truly won over.

Comment: Wow. That fits surprisingly well, apart from the last line.

Comment: I didn't see the other answers until after I posted.

Answer (score 2):

While I think other answers fit better,

You are

> Memories

I slip through your fingers as sand in a sieve.

> Created memories are forgotten in time

A brief moment, an eternity, is when I live.

> Memories are created in an instant, and live on within us

I'm nothing at all, yet I contain everything.

> We humans are a summation of memories, despite not being physically tangible (yet)

Time travellers leave me, but I'm always waiting.

> Memories persist through time with the traveler, and the state of the universe with it, and can be re-implemented (think Back to the Future, specifically when Marty and Doc end up in the alternate timeline where Biff is successful; they set things back to a more favorable state)

I'm always moving, yet you're always within me.

> Memories include the state of the remember-er; e.g. when you remember a childhood birthday party, you are as you were then, not as you are now.

Held between mighty ones who can never win me.

> Not sure how 'Memories' could fit this. Perhaps even those with power and might cannot take your memories?